SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema for id 1
This happens when trying to deserialize using avro. Verified that schema registry URL is correct, and matches the producer.
This error happens in a couple minutes of the container startup. Before the container shuts down, I tried manual curl requests to schema registry URL and verified that schema registry is reachable from here, and the schemas are also present.
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(StreamExecution.scala:211)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at org.apache.spark.JobArtifactSet$.withActiveJobArtifactState(JobArtifactSet.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:211)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkThreadUtils$.awaitResult(SparkThreadUtils.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.perf.DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.awaitShuffleMapStage$1(DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.perf.DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.getShuffleStats(DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.perf.DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.computeBins(DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.perf.DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.doExecute(DeltaOptimizedWriterExec.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doExecute(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.doExecute(SortExec.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeWrite$1(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DeltaFileFormatWriter$.write(DeltaFileFormatWriter.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaSink.$anonfun$addBatchWithStatusImpl$4(DeltaSink.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaSink.addBatchWithStatusImpl(DeltaSink.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaSink.addBatch(DeltaSink.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:286)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:311)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:289)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 67) (172.31.198.57 executor 1): org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema for id 1
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:407)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:188)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:173)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:157)
    at com.adobe.connect.streams.internal.AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroDeserializer.scala:14)
    at com.adobe.connect.streams.internal.source.KafkaSource.$anonfun$toDataset$1(Source.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapElementsExec.$anonfun$doExecute$11(objects.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:577)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:577)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.nextCur(Iterator.scala:587)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:601)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.hasNext(Iterator.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.hasNext(Iterator.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:281)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:386)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:408)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1308)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1241)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1127)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1686)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1610)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:313)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:409)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:916)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:900)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:880)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:333)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:464)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:398)
    ... 29 more
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema for id 1
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:407)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:188)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:173)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:157)
    at com.adobe.connect.streams.internal.AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroDeserializer.scala:14)
    at com.adobe.connect.streams.internal.source.KafkaSource.$anonfun$toDataset$1(Source.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapElementsExec.$anonfun$doExecute$11(objects.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:577)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:577)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.nextCur(Iterator.scala:587)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:601)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.hasNext(Iterator.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.hasNext(Iterator.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:281)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:386)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:408)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1308)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1241)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1127)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1686)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1610)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:313)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:409)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:916)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:900)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:880)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:333)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:464)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:398)
    ... 29 more
24/10/14 08:00:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/10/14 08:00:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-929f654d-a289-41a7-b26f-f96ef14c26b8/spark-bced15f1-d7f2-40a5-8323-c2c270b1bbd1
24/10/14 08:00:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-11534a8d-f49c-4e78-9ca7-c87c2b37b85c

Complete logs [https://pastebin.com/LCqR82Ku][1]
More context - This is a spark structured streaming application to ingest data from kafka into delta lake. I have another open source service running for this ingestion, kafka-delta-ingest. It is also reading from same kafka topic, using same schema registry and delta lake, so other components are all fine.
What could be going wrong?

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused - You have a network error... Is the Registry actually running and/or does it allow connections from Spark? Please share code as a [mcve] not only logs
